# Can someone please translate this photo for me?

Tags: google-translate

Can someone please look at the photo and translate to English for me?[image]

Answer (score 2):

观音福

观音 - [Guanyin](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Guanyin-1694188) (Avalokiteśvara)

- compassionate

福 - blessing